# Chef error on attributes- string not matched

Tags: ruby, chef-infra

I cannot seem to get around a chef error that deals with similarly named attributes in my `attributes/default.rb` file.

I have 2 attributes:

```
default['test']['webservice']['https']['keyManagerPwd'] = 'password'
...
...
default['test']['webservice']['https']['keyManagerPwd']['type'] = 'encrypted'
```

Notice that, up until the last bracket (`['type']`), the names are identical.

I am referencing these attributes in a template and in a template block in the recipe.  When I go to run it, I receive this error:

```
==================================================[0m
I, [2015-01-28T13:36:43.668692 #7920]  INFO -- core-14-2-centos-65: 
[31mRecipe Compile Error
in /tmp/kitchen/cache/cookbooks/avx/attributes/default.rb[0m
I, [2015-01-28T13:36:43.669192 #7920]  INFO -- core-14-2-centos-65: 
=================================================================[0m
I, [2015-01-28T13:36:43.669192 #7920]  INFO -- core-14-2-centos-65: 
I, [2015-01-28T13:36:43.669692 #7920]  INFO -- core-14-2-centos-65:    
[0mIndexError[0m
I, [2015-01-28T13:36:43.669692 #7920]  INFO -- core-14-2-centos-65: -------
--[0m
I, [2015-01-28T13:36:43.669692 #7920]  INFO -- core-14-2-centos-65: string not matched[0m
I, [2015-01-28T13:36:43.670192 #7920]  INFO -- core-14-2-centos-65: 
I, [2015-01-28T13:36:43.670192 #7920]  INFO -- core-14-2-centos-65:
[0mCookbook Trace:[0m
I, [2015-01-28T13:36:43.670692 #7920]  INFO -- core-14-2-centos-65: --------[0m
I, [2015-01-28T13:46:05.101875 #8332]  INFO -- core-14-2-centos-65:     
[0m113>> default['webservice']['https']['keyManagerPwd']['type'] = 
'encrypted'
```

It seems as if Chef cannot distinguish between 2 attributes when the only differentiation is the ending. 
If I modify the same attributes by placing some unique text at the front of the name, there is not issue with the recipe at all:

```
  default['test']['1']['webservice']['https']['keyManagerPwd'] = 'password'
  ...
  ...
  default['test']['2']['webservice']['https']['keyManagerPwd']['type'] = 'encrypted'
```

By putting the `['1']` and `['2']` there, it solves the problem.

I am fairly new to Chef so I'm thinking its just something simple I'm overlooking. Does anyone have any ideas or suggestions?  Thanks.

Answer (score 10):

Simple answer: You cannot do this. That's not a Chef problem, nor a ruby problem - it's a general problem of like most programming languages.

Let's use `foo` as a variable instead of the lengthy `default['test']['webservice']['https']['keyManagerPwd']`.

What you effectively do is

```
1: foo = "password"
2: foo['type'] = "encrypted"
```

In line 1, `foo` is a string. In line 2, it is treated as hash (called array in some other languages). The second line automatically overwrites your `foo = "password"` assignment. It's effectively the same as

```
1: foo = "password"
2: foo = {}
3: foo['type'] = "encrypted"
```

The alternative would be to use

```
foo['something'] = "password"
foo['type'] = "encrypted"
```

Or translated to your code:

```rb
default['test']['webservice']['https']['keyManagerPwd']['something'] = 'password'
default['test']['webservice']['https']['keyManagerPwd']['type'] = 'encrypted'
```

This should work.

Comment: Can't be explained better ;)

Comment: Thank you.  I have no doubt this is what is happening and your alternative solution will work so I will follow that suggestion. Having said that, I am a little unclear how `foo` and `default['test']['webservice']['https']['keyManagerPwd']` are equivalent. I see foo as a string, but the later as a hash itself.

Comment: `foo` and `default['test']['webservice']['https']` are equivalent. Both can be of any type. You can put anything into a hash in ruby.

Comment: (to be clear, what Chef uses here is AFAIK not a plain old ruby hash, but something that looks like a hash and feels like a hash, but is called a [mash](http://www.rubydoc.info/gems/chef/Mash) - but I suggest that you ignore this fact for the moment)

Comment: You're welcome. If it works, feel free to accept the answer (by clicking on the ✓)